# Mulitple animations with and without certain objects

Tags: animation, export, unity

I am currently trying to create a simple RTS game in which I want villagers to be able to mine and walk around. Currently I have two animations implemented (idle and walking). Now I am trying to implement the mining animation. Therefore I created a pickaxe which I want to only be visible in the mining animation and not in the others.
I created a seperate gameobject "pickaxe" and created a single bone armature for it. Then I created the bone constraint "child of" in pose mode and selected the left hand bone.

[image: Mining animation]

So the animation is done but now the villager carries the pickaxe with him all the time. (also in idle and walking).
I tried to use animate the viewport and renderer visibility by inserting a keyframe for those properties. However it seems, that this is then applied to the villager itself as he disapears when starting the animation.
When this is done I want to export this to unity and use it there.
I would be very happy for any kind of help!
Thank you!

Best
Luca

Comment: You could try shrinking it into his pocket or putting it on their back, and if it's not an npc that should be able to mine just hide it with code.

Comment: So you would just add keyframes, where the pickaxe is scaled to 0? I am just worried about computational expences, as I want to make the RTS efficient in order to get as much units as possible while running a smooth game.